# How to embed a TextField into a Movie Clip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a textfield I've positioned within another movieclip using the flash ide. In the library the textfield is clearly visible with a prevalue of 88 set there. When I run the swf the text field isn't there.

As I'm exporting a Piece symbol from flash, my approach has been to look for the object (TextField) in the displayobject container. When I break inside loopStage(this) I have the reference to the textfield i positioned in the editor and can see the prevalue I set there "88".

Can anyone see why I can't see the text field but when debugging can see the reference?

For more info - the textfield sits in its own layer and is on the stage for all frames in the movie clip.

```
    public class Piece extends MovieClip 
    {

            public function Piece() 
            {
                  loopStage(this);
            }

            public function loopStage(dOC:DisplayObjectContainer)
           {
              var child:TextField = dOC.getChildAt(1) as TextField;
              _child = child;

              draw();
           }
           public var _child:TextField;

           public function draw():void
           {
                 _child.text = "1234";
           }

    }
```

Thanks

Edit: Thanks for all comments guys! Much appreciated...

Font embedding was done incorrectly on my part - what made the difference was after I filled the embed font dialog and gave it a name "Abc" - i forgot to select "Abc" from the font list and apply it to the TextField. Gah!

Happy to mark that answer as correct thanks again! :)

Comment: Sounds like you didnt embed fonts !

Comment: Indeed sir - if you place an answer up I'll mark it thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you forgot to embed the font used in the TextField.

Answer (score 0):

...maybe you're forgetting `addChild(_child);`?

You created the variable, but you're forgetting to add it.

Okay, so maybe d0c is what you're adding it to.  So tell me, what is the X and Y position of it?  Could you maybe define that?  `trace` your values.

[EDIT]
In the comments it notes to embed your fonts, or it might not show.

Comment: It's added to the display list from Flash Pro's artboard.

Comment: But you should trace to see where it's location lies, probably 0,0.

Comment: It is fairly easy to test if this a font embedding issue. Just set `_child.text = "18"` and if you see only `8` on screen, then you are missing a font embedding.

Comment: @Pooyan Arab good point!  But maybe he should test it with 'every' number?

Comment: Thanks for this answer - it looks like just a font embedding issue after all.